# running terminal command using java to clear terminal history

Tags: java

I want to get terminal history
So I did this

```
Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
pr = rt.exec("/bin/bash -c \"history -c\"");
pr.waitFor();
rt.exec("/usr/bin/xterm");
```

but there is problem with pr = rt.exec("/bin/bash -c \"history -c\""); , it's not clearing the previous history nither of xterm nor my normal terminal.

Also when I try to print the history it returns nothing (no errors)

```
p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("/bin/bash -c \"history\"");
p.waitFor();
BufferedReader reader = 
         new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));

String line = "";       
System.out.println("printing");
while ((line = reader.readLine())!= null) {
    output.append(line + "\n");
}
```

I also tried

```
String[] commands = new String[]{"/bin/sh","-c", "history -c" ,"xterm"};
try {
        Process proc = new ProcessBuilder(commands).start();
        BufferedReader stdInput = new BufferedReader(new 
                    InputStreamReader(proc.getInputStream()));

        BufferedReader stdError = new BufferedReader(new 
                        InputStreamReader(proc.getErrorStream()));
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
```

still not clearing history.

Comment: I think that `history` and `-c` should be two arguments. That means calling `rt.exec(new String[] { "history", "-c" }`.

Comment: @PavelHoral did this 'rt.exec(new String[] {"/bin/bash","-c", "history", "-c" });
     rt.exec("/usr/bin/xterm");' still not working

Comment: Are you running your application from within eclipse or some other IDE? Or from the command line?

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Tried this `File file = new File("$HOME/.bash_history");
    if(file.delete()){
        System.out.println(file.getName() + " is deleted!");
       }else{
        System.out.println("Delete operation is failed.");
       }` going in else loop.

Comment: @SteveC for now eclipse

Comment: Eclipse does not run with the same environment setup as your bash command line. You need to emulate the settings from your ~/.bash_profile (or whatever you happen to be using) in the "Environment" tab of the "Run Configuration" that you're using to execute your program.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the history file yourself by getting the $HISTFILE environment variable. This will always get the correct history file for different shells. I believe the issue you're having is that the you may be using a different shell or have changed your history file location.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class RemoveShellHistory {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        RemoveShellHistory obj = new RemoveShellHistory();

        final String shellPath = System.getenv("SHELL");
        String shell = shellPath.substring(shellPath.lastIndexOf("/")+1, shellPath.length());
        final String home  = System.getenv("HOME");

        String command = "rm -v " + home + "/." + shell + "_history";
        String output = obj.executeCommand(command);

        System.out.println(output);
    }

    private String executeCommand(String command) {
        StringBuffer output = new StringBuffer();
        Process p;
        try {
            p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
            p.waitFor();
            BufferedReader reader =
            new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
            String line = "";
            while ((line = reader.readLine())!= null) {
                output.append(line + "\n");
            }
            } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return output.toString();
    }
}
```

Comment: not working( no errors). System.getenv("HISTFILE") is returning null.

Comment: `$HISTFILE` seems to be a shell var and not a env var. I updated the script to just remove the `.shell_history` file.

Comment: The shell will still write out a new copy on exit.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your java app runs by the same user possessing the .bash_history file:

To delete.

```
new File(System.getProperty("user.home"), ".bash_history").delete();
```

To clean (Handle the checked exception at your will).

```
    FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(
        new File(System.getProperty("user.home"), ".bash_history"));
    writer.write("");
    writer.close();
```